# Form in JQTouch

Tags: jqtouch

I have tried jqtouch and I have trouble getting a form with php to work in Safari. Nothing happens when I press submit in Safari but It works in Explorer. I tried to change input type from submit to button but it didn't help. How should I change my code?

```
<?php
function test1()
{
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$test = $_POST['test'];

echo $test;

}
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post" class="form">
<table>
<br />

<tr>
<td><label for="test">Test:</label></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="test"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><br /><input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Press"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are using jQTouch?  The code you have posted doesn't appear to use jQTouch at all, just basic PHP code.